# error 'Is inaccessible due to its protection level - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get this error on Visual Studio (with Unity) (C# version 7.2):

> Volume/BuilderInstance.cs(32,32): Error CS0122: 'Lazy' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122)

This is the code:

```
using System;

namespace ConvNetSharp.Volume {

public class BuilderInstance<T> where T : struct, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable {
    public static readonly Lazy<VolumeBuilder<T>> Singleton = new Lazy<VolumeBuilder<T>>(Create);
    public static VolumeBuilder<T> Volume { get; set; } = Singleton.Value;

    public static VolumeBuilder<T> Create() {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(double)) {
            return (VolumeBuilder<T>)(object)new Double.VolumeBuilder();
        }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(float)) {
            return (VolumeBuilder<T>)(object)new Single.VolumeBuilder();
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException(
            $"Volumes of type '{typeof(T).Name}' are not supported. Only Double and Single are supported.");
    }
}

}
```

I get the error at the Lazy variable declaration!
Why? any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: I'd guess that the `Lazy` type has a private constructor and can't be invoked via new, but I'm unfamiliar with the library. Can you "go to definition" on Lazy and see what the class/method signatures look like?

Comment: What's the point in even using Lazy if you're immediately accessing it's value?

Comment: If you hover over `Lazy`, what fully-qualified name is it reporting? My guess is that you've got an internal type somewhere which is hiding `System.Lazy<T>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet it says that is inaccessible!

Comment: I don't see that you've answered my question at all. I'm asking for the fully-qualified type name that it's saying is inaccessible.

Comment: @Basic if I go to declaration I found the constructor (there is the definition)!

Comment: (It would also be useful to know which version of Unity3d you're using, and which scripting runtime you're targeting.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, I changed the line with 'System.Lazy' instead of 'Lazy'

Comment: @FrancescoScala: Do you mean "I get the same error if I explicitly use `System.Lazy<VolumeBuilder<T>>` instead of `Lazy<VolumeBuilder<T>>`"? It's not clear...

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using Unity 2017.3 and runtime 5.4.1.7

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I've done that

Comment: Sorry, I mean which version of the Mono runtime you're targeting. When you say that you can "go to declaration" - where does that take you? Does it show which assembly it's in? Is it declared as a public type? (I wouldn't be surprised if an internal-only version was bundled in some cases.)

Comment: @JonSkeet the mono version that i'm using is 5.4.1.7, when I click on see declaration it brings to me to assembly declaration and the constructors are all public

Comment: I don't think Unity will use Mono 5.4.1.7 at execution time, even if the editor uses it. The setting I'm asking about is the project-specific one - under "Build Settings / Player Settings", it's called "Scripting Runtime Version". The option for "API Compatibility Level" would be useful. Please edit your question to specify both of those.

Comment: @JonSkeet unity says - Runtime: 3.5, Api compatibility: 2.0

Comment: Right. `Lazy<T>` was introduced into .NET 4.0, so I'm not surprised it's unavailable. While you checked that the *constructors* were public, did you check the access level of the type itself? (That's what I asked about.) I suspect that Unity includes an assembly with a bunch of .NET 4 types declared as internal, just to make their lives easier.

Comment: @JonSkeet perfect I've changed the Runtime inside Unity and now it works! Thank you very much